# Firebase onAuthStateChanged not running as expected in React App

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication

**So i am building a React+redux app using firebase. I'm using react-router onEnter callback function(checkAuth) for route protection.**

```
export default function getRoutes (checkAuth) {
  return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={MainContainer}>
          <IndexRoute component = {HomeContainer} onEnter = {checkAuth}/>
          <Route path='auth' component = {AuthenticateContainer} onEnter = {checkAuth} />
          <Route path='feed' component = {FeedContainer} onEnter = {checkAuth} />
          <Route path='logout' component = {LogoutContainer} />
        </Route>
      </Router>
  )
}
```

**the checkAuth function calls checkIfAuthed function to see if there is a currentUser.**

```
function checkAuth (nextState, replace) {
  const isAuthed = checkIfAuthed(store)
  console.log('isAuthed from checkAuth method', isAuthed)
  const nextPathName = nextState.location.pathname
  console.log('nextPathName', nextPathName)
  // debugger
  if (nextPathName === '/' || nextPathName === 'auth') {
    if (isAuthed === true) {
      // debugger
      replace('feed')
    }
  } else {
    // debugger
    if (isAuthed !== true) {
      // debugger
      replace('auth')
    }
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store = {store}>
    {getRoutes(checkAuth)}
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

**The checkIfAuthed function looks like this:**

```
export function checkIfAuthed (store) {
  // debugger
  // const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    console.log('isAuthed from on state changed', user)
    // debugger
    if (user === null) {
      // debugger
      return false
    } else if (store.getState().isAuthed === false) {
      // debugger
      const userInfo = formatUserInfo(user.displayName, user.photoURL, user.uid)
      // debugger
      store.dispatch(authUser(user.uid))
      // debugger
      store.dispatch(fetchingUserSuccess(user.uid, userInfo))
      // debugger
      return true
    }
    // debugger
    return true
  })
}
```

**However, const *isAuthed* is always undefined at runtime in the checkAuth() function.thus leading to replace("feed") never running. I was expecting it to be false or true.**

Additionally if I instead use const user = firebase.auth().currentUser in the checkIfAuthed function the Replace function runs but this requires user to hit login button, whereas the firebase observer above automatically runs.

Answer (score 0):

You can check here this implementation

The Service when we read the user auth and set the value to Redux https://github.com/x-team/unleash/blob/develop/app/services/authService.js

The reducer when set the user state to the redux state object https://github.com/x-team/unleash/blob/develop/app/reducers/userReducer.js

The action creators https://github.com/x-team/unleash/blob/develop/app/actions/UserActions.js

The login state check
https://github.com/x-team/unleash/blob/develop/app/components/UnleashApp.jsx#L17

The most important part is the authService, let me know any question